# Marketing Cloud Triggered Send does not work

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I'm trying to create a Triggered Send but although it has been activated the contacts who accomplish the Triggered Send conditions does not receive the email.

I connected Marketing Cloud with Sales Cloud Sandbox and I enabled the object (named Inquiry) in Marketing Cloud Connector Settings:
[image]

This is the configured trigger:

```
trigger Z_InquiryTrigger on TargetX_SRMb__Inquiry__c (
  before insert, 
  before update, 
  before delete, 
  after insert, 
  after update, 
  after delete, 
  after undelete) {

  Z_TriggerFactory.createHandler(TargetX_SRMb__Inquiry__c.sObjectType);
    if (Z_Constants.TargetX_SRMb_Inquiry_MCController && Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate))
    {
        et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('TargetX_SRMb__Inquiry__c'); 
    }
}
```

Finally, this is how I have configured the Triggered Send in Sales Cloud:

[image]

I don't know where is the issue, I think everything is well configured. Could somebody help me?

Thank you,
Anna

Comment: Check if the associated email related to this triggered send is working fine. Sometimes if you have ampscript in email make sure you handle the salesforce data properly. Also, if the Org is new then check if you have added physical mailing address & profile update.

Comment: I have checked if the associated email is working fine sending an email and it worked well. In addition, I have checked the other points you suggest and everything is ok but it still not working. Thank  you for your help :)